# How do admin rights and shared network drives interact with git?

Tags: git, github

I want to have an easy workflow with git. Once at work checking out an old commit and then the master made me lose the whole project. The error message said I didn't have access to the folder. I assume this is either because a) I was on a shared network drive, or b) I don't have admin permissions at work.

How do admin rights/shared network drives interact with git? Should I be safe doing things off my local drive, at least?

I used to connect my projects to my user profile, but that has caused my profile to bloat and load for a long time in the mornings. My stuff is now on github, but I can't really imagine working by literally looking at all previous commits off github instead of in my IDE...

Comment: You get to keep your local repo and have a remote (or multiple remotes) associated (the github repo), and then you work locally and push/pull whenever you feel like to github... so you get to work with your IDE the way you have always done.

Comment: And I think git does not have support for any filesharing stuff... it only works on filesystem as the OS makes it available.... so as long as your user has access to a certain resource (even if through network), as long as it looks "mounted" locally and permissins are set up correctly to be able to read/write stuff, it will work.

Comment: Git knows nothing about administrative issues, shared drives, and so on: it just believes, quite strongly, that only Git controls things inside the `.git` directory/folder. Whatever happens in your work-tree is up to you, so you could share that and Git would believe that any sharing-originated changes were made by you while Git was not looking.